# python --path=/path/to/my/module/?

Tags: python, pythonpath

Is it possible to specify directories to search for python imports in the python startup command?

Environment variables are great but the loosely coupled dependency between a binary and required environment variables isn't ideal for my case (a 1-liner is better than a 2 liner for extra foolproofness; I know you can do the 1.5 liner where you put the shell variable assignment as a prefix to the command you're about to execute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` environmental variable is used to set [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). It is a simple list of strings so you can always use `sys.path.append` inside your module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/some/very/useful/path')
```

Note:

It can be particularly useful when combined with `os.path.abspath`

```
 import os
 sys.path.append(os.path.join(
         os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'another/useful/directory'
 ))
```

Comment: That's an acceptable solution for my hello world samples. Thanks.